# login with admin and user using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, admin

help me please. I'm a newbie. Found this solution here too. The authentication worked but the redirection part doesn't. It always redirects to Default.Aspx tho the admins should be redirected to Add.aspx Please help :'( Thanks in advance!

Here's my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace CRUD
{
public partial class Login1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string conn = "";
        conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["employee1ConnectionString"].ToString();
        SqlConnection objsqlconn = new SqlConnection(conn);
        objsqlconn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from userdata where username=@username and password=@password", objsqlconn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox1.Text);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (dt.Rows[0]["permission"].ToString() == "admin")
                Response.Redirect("Add.aspx");
            else
                Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");

        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "Invalid username or password. Please try again.";
        }

    }
}
}
```

and...

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login1.aspx.cs" Inherits="CRUD.Login1"       %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    .style1
    {
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

</div>
<p class="style1">
    LOG IN</p>
<p class="style1">
    &nbsp;</p>
<p class="style1">
    Username:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="167px"></asp:TextBox>
</p>
<p class="style1">
    Password:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Width="167px"></asp:TextBox>
</p>
<p class="style1">
```

Not a member yet? Click 
        here
        .

Table structure:
db: userdata
-username
-password
-permission

Comment: What is the value of `dt.Rows[0]["permission"].ToString()` when you debug your code? And don't store your passwords as a plain text.

Comment: debug your code, there might be some fault

Comment: I agree with @SonerGönül, not to store password as plain text

Comment: Hi Soner, my permission values are "admin" or "user"

Comment: what do you mean not to store password as plain text?

Comment: both username and password TextBox1.Text ?  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox1.Text);

Answer (score 1):

You are giving both the `textbox1` value to password as well. make the changes as below

```
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text);
```

Please put your code in proper syntax and check:-

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string conn = "";
    conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["employee1ConnectionString"].ToString();
    SqlConnection objsqlconn = new SqlConnection(conn);
    objsqlconn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from userdata where username=@username and password=@password", objsqlconn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox1.Text);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    da.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        if (dt.Rows[0]["permission"].ToString() == "admin")
        {
            Response.Redirect("Add.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        }

    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "Invalid username or password. Please try again.";
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, yeah. Sorry just mistaken. Already fixed it but it's still the same :(

Comment: did u debugged your code ? what value are you getting at dt.Rows[0]["permission"].ToString()?

Comment: I did. When I pass it to a label, it gets admin or user. :( But do not redirect.

Comment: Please share your full code and table structure, will check it and let you know

Comment: will try! :) Thank you so much Sir Nadeem. I'll update you. I edited my post too, you can see my full code

Comment: wait, I am working on your code, you have not specified the things properly. Give me sometime. I will Update you

Comment: you want to insert the data or just want for Select statement ?

Comment: I'd like to get its permission. For eg. username: fel password: pass. Fel's permission is admin. Once Fel logged in she would be redirected to the admin page. Discussed my table on my question too. My goal is too redirect admins and users to their corresponding pages.

Comment: which version of VS are you using ?

Comment: @Fel:will it be OK, if I change the whole code, As I am using the LoginControl of the asp.net, which provides basic yet simple and fullproof loggin system.It will be working as per your need